# How do you duplicate a div tag?

Tags: jquery

How can I duplicate  the `#DvRefer` element with its contents when the user clicks on the `#Duplicate` button?

```
<div id='DvRefer'>
    <div style="float: right; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">name:</div>
    <select id="LstRefer" runat="server" style="margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 14px;float: right; margin-left: 8px; width: 205px;">
    </select>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="text-align: left">
    <input id="Duplicate" type="button" runat="server" value="Duplicate" class="buttons" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cloneCount = 0;
$("#Duplicate").click(function() {
    $("#DvRefer").clone()
        .attr("id", "DvRefer_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .insertAfter("#DvRefer");
    $("#LstRefer", "#DvRefer_Clone" + cloneCount)
        .attr("id", "LstRefer_Clone" + cloneCount);
    cloneCount++;
});
```

You can see I've also changed the `id` of the cloned element to avoid having duplicate ids, which is invalid, and will cause you problems.

**Update**

Fixed to account for multiple cloned divs. If you don't want to use a global variable, you could instead use a hidden input element to store the counter.

Comment: Thanks for your help.but if user clicks more than two times on Duplicate button I'll have duplicate Ids.

Comment: and what about `select tag` id?

Comment: Just take the length of the DvRefers and add one.

Comment: @MetalFrog there will only ever be one `#DvRefers`, and the clones will each have different IDs. You could use the attribute begins with selector for the clones' ID, but I hate using that as it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function. Here's an example taken from the site:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');
```